# Remove "x" from kendo combobox

Tags: angular, typescript, combobox, kendo-ui

How to remove/hide the clear ("x") action from a kendo combobox in typescript?

I've tried looking for a scss/css way but haven't solved my problem at all. Also it's even ok to me if there is a way to stop the propagation of the event caused by pressing that x. Sadly, as I found, it's all binded to the "change" event and, if I'm right, there's no way to stop the emit.

Comment: Can't you just set the clearbutton property of the combobox to false? https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/combobox#configuration-clearButton

Answer (score 2):

Use `::ng-deep`:

```
::ng-deep kendo-combobox .k-clear-value {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Note that this is planned to be deprecated in the future but there is no alternative at the moment.

There are other aliases to this, `>>>` and `/deep/`, which have a "higher deprecation priority" so using `::ng-deep` is best, until an alternative is created.

Answer (score 2):

As Ezanker commented, there is a *clearButton* property to set as input on the kendo-combobox selector. Default is true, set it to false. [Here API docs.](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/api/ComboBoxComponent/#toc-inputs)